# Android Emulator for Visual Studio stuck at "Preparing Virtual Machine.."

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, emulator

I wanted to get into Xamarin, but I have a problem. Whenever I try to run any of the settings in the android emulator, the warning "You do not have permission to modify internal Hyper-V network adapter settings" pop-up. Since I have the admin rights, I just click "Retry"(with admin rights). However, after I click the "Retry" button, the emulator gets stuck at "Preparing virtual machine..." .

I've rebooted, reinstalled the emulator, and made sure that Hyper-v was on, yet the problem persists. Also, I am in the Hyper-V admin group, DNS is automatically configured, DHCP is enabled, and (not sure if this changes anything, but) I use VPN. I don't want to turn Hyper-V off. How can I get the emulator to run? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:actually, I do not see emulator option that begin from vsemulator in visual studio. Does that mean the emulator is not properly installed?